# Curious behavior with errors.As in go

Tags: go

I'm building an api in golang using chi.

I created a wrapper in my handler functions to intercept and identify errors

```
func BuildHandler(db *sql.DB) *chi.Mux {
    // Repositories
    userRepository := user.NewRepository(db)

    // Api Handlers
    authHandler := auth.NewAuthAPIHandler(userRepository)

    r := chi.NewRouter()
    // r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)

    r.Method("POST", "/auth/login", handler.Handler(authHandler.Login()))

    return r
}
```

```
type Handler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error

func (h Handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := h(w, r); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(err))

        var valErrs validator.ValidationErrors
        if errors.As(err, &valErrs) {
            fmt.Println("called here")
        }

        w.Write([]byte("error"))
    }
}
```

```
func (a *AuthAPI) Login() handler.Handler {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
        var loginDTO LoginDTO

        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&loginDTO)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        email, err := a.service.Login(r.Context(), loginDTO)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(err))
            return err
        }

        w.Write([]byte(email))
        return nil
    }
}
```

both places with reflect return the type `validator.ValidationErrors`, however "errorsAs" does not work within ServeHTTP, but works within the login handler.

What can it be ?

I would like errorsAs to work within ServeHTTP

Comment: You did not show what `LoginDTO` is, but the fact that it works means that `LoginDTO` implements the correct interface or value. Normally you would want that implemented by a pointer, not the value, so `valErrs` probably needs to be a pointer. Notice the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#example-As) uses a pointer for the examples to highlight this.

Comment: yes, the `loginDTO` value is being filled. putting the pointer in `valErrs` didn't solve the problem =/

Comment: Then you need to show a [mre]. We can’t guess what the types and error values are.

Comment: I discovered the problem... in one connection I was using the import `"github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"` in another `"github.com/go-playground/validator"` so the signatures were incompatible